# Problem in firefox when calling window.open

Tags: javascript, oracle-xe, oracle-apex

When i'm calling this code in the link of a chart in apex

`javascript:window.open('http://google.pt','mywindow','width=400,height=200', 'bReplace=true');`

it opens a new window with google page but puts the chart page with a blank page with `[object Window]` wrote on it

How can i maintain the chart page?

Comment: Just a note: This happened to me in IE as well when clicking a link on a pop up page.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to force the expresion to not return a value:

```
javascript:void(window.open(...))
```

Comment: How do we do in angular 2 or higher?

Comment: @LEVEL: Use click handlers, not `javascript:` URIs.